# RDS User logoff Script Slow

Tags: powershell, rds, logoff

With the help of the several online articles I was able to compile a powershell script that logs off all users for each of my RD Session hosts.  I wanted something to be really gentle on logging off users and it writing profiles back to their roaming profile location on the storage system.  However,  this is too gentle and takes around four hours to complete with the amount of users and RDS servers I have.

This script is designed to set each RDS server drain but allow redirection if a server is available so the thought around this was within the first 15 minutes I would have the first few servers ready for users to log into.

All of this works but I would like like to see if there are any suggestions on speeding this up a little.

Here is the loop that goes through each server and logs users out and then sets the server logon mode to enabled:

```
ForEach ($rdsserver in $rdsservers){
    try {
        query user /server:$rdsserver 2>&1 | select -skip 1 | ? {($_ -split "\s+")[-5]} | % {logoff ($_ -split "\s+")[-6] /server:$rdsserver /V}


        Write-Host "Giving the RDS Server time"
        Write-Progress "Pausing Script" -status "Giving $rdsserver time to settle" -perc (5/(5/100))
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5




        $RDSH=Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_TerminalServiceSetting" -Namespace "root\CIMV2\terminalservices" -ComputerName $rdsserver -Authentication PacketPrivacy -Impersonation Impersonate
        $RDSH.SessionBrokerDrainMode=0
        $RDSH.put() > $null
        Write-Host "$rdsserver is set to:"
        switch ($RDSH.SessionBrokerDrainMode) {
            0 {"Allow all connections."}
            1 {"Allow incoming reconnections but until reboot prohibit new connections."}
            2 {"Allow incoming reconnections but prohibit new connections."}
        default {"The user logon state cannot be determined."}
        }
    } 
    catch {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how many Servers you have but if its less than 50 or so you can do this in parallel with PSJobs.  You'll have to wrap your code in a scriptblock, launch each server as a separate job, then wait for them to complete and retrieve any data returned.  You won't be able to use Write-Host when doing this but I've swapped those to Out-Files.  I also didn't parse out your code for collecting your list of servers but I'm going to assume that works and you can have it return a formatted list to a variable `$rdsservers`.  You'll probably also want to modify the messages a bit so you can tell which server is which in the log file, or do different logs for each server.  If you want anything other than the names of jobs to hit the console you'll have to output it with `Write-Output` or a `return` statement.

```
$SB = {
param($rdsserver)
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

$RDSH=Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_TerminalServiceSetting" -Namespace "root\CIMV2\terminalservices" -ComputerName $rdsserver -Authentication PacketPrivacy -Impersonation Impersonate
$RDSH.SessionBrokerDrainMode=0
$RDSH.put() > $null
"$rdsserver is set to:" | out-file $LogPath #Set this to whatever you want
switch ($RDSH.SessionBrokerDrainMode) {
    0 {"Allow all connections." | out-file $LogPath}
    1 {"Allow incoming reconnections but until reboot prohibit new connections." | out-file $LogPath}
    2 {"Allow incoming reconnections but prohibit new connections." | out-file $LogPath}
    default {"The user logon state cannot be determined." | out-file $LogPath}
}

foreach ($server in $rdsservers){
  Start-Job -Scriptblock -ArgumentList $server
}

Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

The foreach loop launches the jobs and then the last line waits for all of them to complete before getting any data that was output.  You can also set a timeout on the wait if there is a chance your script never completes.  If you've got a ton of boxes you may want to look into runspaces over jobs as they have better performance but take more work to use.  [This Link](https://learn-powershell.net/2012/05/13/using-background-runspaces-instead-of-psjobs-for-better-performance/) can help you out if you decide to go that way.  I don't have an RDS deployment at the moment to test on so if you get any errors or have trouble getting it to work just post a comment and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thanks this is good information and I'm going to give this a try.     Lets say I want to throttle the jobs that run in the background.    Is there something I can add to this to run three or four jobs then move on to the next set of servers?

Comment: You can do something like that using a while loop and some recursive functions but it's a pain, if you want throttling look into runspaces as they provide it natively, the link provided shows how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I have something ready for testing but it may break fantastically.   You wizards out there may look at this and laugh.    If i did this wrong please let me know.

```
$Serverperbatch = 2
$job = 0
$job = $Serverperbatch - 1 
$batch = 1

While ($job -lt $rdsservers.count) {
    $ServerBatch = $rdsservers[$job .. $job]
    $jobname = "batch$batch"
Start-job -Name $jobname -ScriptBlock {
    param ([string[]]$rdsservers)
    Foreach ($rdsserver in $rdsservers) {
        try {
    query user /server:$rdsserver 2>&1 | select -skip 1 | ? {($_ -split "\s+")[-5]} | % {logoff ($_ -split "\s+")[-6] /server:$rdsserver /V}
    $RDSH=Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_TerminalServiceSetting" -Namespace "root\CIMV2\terminalservices" -ComputerName $rdsserver -Authentication PacketPrivacy -Impersonation Impersonate
    $RDSH.SessionBrokerDrainMode=0
    $RDSH.put() > $null
   }
     catch {}

} -ArgumentList (.$serverbatch)
    $batch += 1
    $Job = $job + 1
    $job += $serverperbatch

    If ($Job -gt $rdsservers.Count) {$Job = $rdsservers.Count}
    If ($Job -gt $rdsservers.Count) {$Job = $rdsservers.Count}
  }
}
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```